# how to get selected am/pm from datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

[image][image]

TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(RemindersSpecificDateActivity.this, RemindersSpecificDateActivity.this, hour, minute, false);
timePickerDialog.show();

```
@Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int h, int t) {
        ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup) timePicker.getChildAt(0);
        Toast.makeText(RemindersSpecificDateActivity.this, myHour+":"+minute+":"+((Button)vg.getChildAt(2)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

this solution does not work

when 24hour is false it returns 3 in both 3pm or 3am . how to identify the difference. Please check the screenshot when 3pm is selected

Comment: probably it returns the int h as 24 hours and you need to convert

Comment: As far as I am aware, the `onTimeSet` method gives you the time in 24 hour format, so it's nothing to do with the time picker, just simple time processing.

Comment: Also note that you are printing myHour+":"+minute and not the h+":"+t returned from the picker

Comment: getChildAt(0) and getChildAt(2) on Android components is a hack that is not suposed to work in other devices and other android versions

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos please check the attached screenshot when i have selected 3 pm hours returns as 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
private void showTimePicker() {
    MaterialTimePicker materialTimePicker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
        .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
        .setHour(4)
        .setMinute(40)
        .build();

    materialTimePicker.show(requireFragmentManager(), "fragment_tag");

    materialTimePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(dialog -> {
      int newHour = materialTimePicker.getHour();
      int newMinute = materialTimePicker.getMinute();
      onTimeSet(newHour, newMinute);
    });
  }
```

call below fuc to get formated time

```
private void onTimeSet(int newHour, int newMinute) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, newHour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, newMinute);
    cal.setLenient(false);

    String format = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
    textView.setText(format);
  }
```

Make sure to add material lib in gradle file to use Material Time picker